# Is a R function or loop to make matrix of results Durbin watson or Linear regresion of every pair of column?

Tags: r

I have a question about R coding. I want to make loop to compute Durbin Watson for every possible pair of column in data set. I got 28 columns.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you regarding linear regression. Slight modifications will make it work for DW test.

You have a total of 378 possible pairs: do you really want to apply 378 regressions ?

The example I propose is based on `mtcars`

```r
head(mtcars)
```

You first compute all 2 by 2 combinations of your columns except those that involve the first column (dependent variable)

```r
combinations <- combn(colnames(mtcars)[-1], m = 2L, simplify = FALSE)
```

You loop over those combinations and output a performance statistics, e.g. rsquared

```r
perf <- lapply(combinations, function(cols){
  ols <- lm(
    formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", paste(cols, collapse = "+"))),
    data = mtcars
  )
  summary(ols)$r.squared
})

names(perf) <- sapply(combinations, paste, collapse = "_")

perf[1:5]
$cyl_disp
[1] 0.7595658

$cyl_hp
[1] 0.7407084

$cyl_drat
[1] 0.7402482

$cyl_wt
[1] 0.8302274

$cyl_qsec
[1] 0.7373272
```

And you rename to get which columns have produced the result

## Update

Now if you want to get all pairs, whatever the order:

```r
list_countries <- combn(c("France","Spain","Germany"), 2L, simplify = FALSE)

list_countries <- c(list_countries,
  lapply(list_countries, function(l) rev(l)) 
)

list_countries
[[1]]
[1] "France" "Spain" 

[[2]]
[1] "France"  "Germany"

[[3]]
[1] "Spain"   "Germany"

[[4]]
[1] "Spain"  "France"

[[5]]
[1] "Germany" "France" 

[[6]]
[1] "Germany" "Spain"
```

`rev` is a base function to reverse the order of a vector. Then, if you want to apply one as dependent variable and the other as explanatory, you would do

```r
perf <- lapply(list_countries, function(cols){
  ols <- lm(as.formula(paste(cols, collapse = "~")),
            data = df)
  )
  summary(ols)$r.squared
})
```

Comment: But it's still compute the same variables, and u get the same values.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. In the example given, some R2 are different. A reproducible example would help if you think there's an error.

Comment: i did likeu said: 
'mt <- read_excel("1.xlsx", col_names = T)

combinations <- combn(colnames(mt)[-1], m = 2L, simplify = FALSE)

perf <- lapply(combinations, function(cols){
  ols <- dwtest(lm(
    formula = as.formula(paste0("Belgia ~ ", paste(cols, sep = "+"))),
    data = mt
  ))
  ols$statistic
})

names(perf) <- sapply(combinations, paste, collapse = "_")'
and example results:
'$Greece_Italy
        DW 
0.03663577 

$Greece_Cyprus
        DW 
0.03663577 

$Greece_Latvia
        DW 
0.03663577 

$Greece_Lithuania
        DW 
0.03663577'

Comment: Ok I understand now. There was a typo in the first paste (only the first variable was used). I corrected, you can check try your example

Comment: Ye, now working thank you for help, one more question, is possible to get every possible pair? Even the inverse? For example: France is my dependent variable and Spain not dependent variable, so i want the invers of this where Spain is dependent variable and Franc not dependent variable? Thank you once more.

Comment: Yes that's possible. I updated the answer. If it answers your question, could you accept the answer [see guidelines here if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you very much for help <3